# Registros duplicados no SQL - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Bom dia, sou novo aqui e estou com um problema chato. O Distinct não resolve meu problema pois a duplicação se deve pelo fato que tive de fazer o relacionamento com outras tabelas para buscar informações. O SQL me retorna dois valores com supervisores diferentes para o mesmo IDCHAMADO, como faço pra exibir somente um IDCHAMADO de forma a não duplicar os registros?

```
SELECT ch.idchamado,su.nome AS nomesupervisor,
  e.nome,
  ch.dataabertura,
  ch.datafechamento,
  ta.desctipoassunto
FROM sase_chamado ch
LEFT JOIN vw_app_consulta_escolas e
ON ch.idpj = e.idpessoa_juridica
LEFT JOIN sase_tipoassunto ta
ON ta.idtipoassunto = ch.idtipoassunto
LEFT JOIN sase_escolasusuario eu
ON eu.idpj = ch.idpj
INNER JOIN sase_usuario su
ON eu.idusuario = su.idusuario
WHERE ch.dataabertura BETWEEN to_date('01/01/16', 'dd/mm/yy') AND to_date('30/07/16', 'dd/mm/yy')
ORDER BY su.nome,
  e.nome,
  ta.desctipoassunto
```

a danada da duplicidade é desse tipo aqui:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você quer apenas um idchamado não importando quantos su.nome tenha? isso vale para o restante dos campos?

Comment: Sim, de forma a não trazer 2 idchamado iguais. o unico campo diferente quando duplica é o proprio nome do supervisor.

Comment: Samuel, se você não quer que gere uma linha distinta para cada supervisor você não pode mostrar o resultado do campo su.nome no seu SELECT (deve remover também da cláusula ORDER BY e aplicar o DISTINCT ou GROUP BY). Caso você queira mostrar o nome dele com esta estrutura você sempre mostrará 1 linha para cada nome de supervisor. É possível (não sei especificamente se no Oracle é) também unir o nome de N supervisores em uma única coluna e uma linha, mas ai você deve mudar consideravelmente seu SELECT.

Comment: Acontece que não posso tirar o su.nome do SELECT pois preciso dele para atribuir o chamado há o nome de um supervisor. o distinct só funciona quando o registro é totalmente igual, mas no meu caso o nome do supervisor muda quando duplica, então não funfa

Comment: Neste caso você não pode agrupar as linhas realmente e deve recuperar ambos os resultados, se você tem duas linhas (se eu entendi a lógica da consulta) é por que há duas chamadas, cada uma para um supervisor, sendo que os demais dados são idênticos.

Comment: acho q eh isso msm, so nao sei como resolver essa duplicidade kkk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando temos queremos apenas uma linha sem nos importar com o conteúdo usamos o MIN ou MAX e agrupamos o que é igual.

```
SELECT ch.idchamado AS idchamado, 
  MIN( su.nome ) AS nomesupervisor,
  e.nome,
  ch.dataabertura,
  ch.datafechamento,
  ta.desctipoassunto
FROM sase_chamado ch
LEFT JOIN vw_app_consulta_escolas e
ON ch.idpj = e.idpessoa_juridica
LEFT JOIN sase_tipoassunto ta
ON ta.idtipoassunto = ch.idtipoassunto
LEFT JOIN sase_escolasusuario eu
ON eu.idpj = ch.idpj
INNER JOIN sase_usuario su
ON eu.idusuario = su.idusuario
WHERE ch.dataabertura BETWEEN to_date('01/01/16', 'dd/mm/yy') AND to_date('30/07/16', 'dd/mm/yy')
GROUP BY 
  ch.idchamado 
  e.nome,
  ch.dataabertura,
  ch.datafechamento,
  ta.desctipoassunto
ORDER BY su.nome,
  e.nome,
  ta.desctipoassunto
```

Comment: Reginaldo, se a data tive como DateTime seu group by não vai funcionar muito bem.

Comment: Verdade. Ele poderia coloca-la como fora do GROUP BY e no MIN também.

Comment: ORA-00933: comando SQL não encerrado adequadamente
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Erro na linha: 19 Coluna: 3

Comment: Consegui arrumar esse erro adicionando o su.nome no GROUP BY, porém continua trazendo duplicado.

Comment: Poste o resultado para a gente ver.

Comment: postei a img da duplicidade amigo, obrigad

Comment: Nome é string o min não dá certo

Comment: nome é varchar2

Comment: Funciona sim @MarconcílioSouza. Acabei de testar. Chega ser inacreditável que o Samuel  esteja rodando esse select com o MIN e o GROUP BY.

Comment: O que você me recomenda Reginaldo para resolver isso? existe alguma forma de eu limitar a consulta a não exibir o mesmo IDCHAMADO duas vezes?

Comment: Veja assim: 
SELECT MIN( ch.idchamado ) AS idchamado, 
  MIN( su.nome ) AS nomesupervisor,
  MIN( e.nome ) AS nome,
  MIn( ch.dataabertura ) AS dataabertura,
  MIN( ch.datafechamento ) AS datafechamento,
  MIN( ta.desctipoassunto )  AS desctipoassunto

Comment: Tire a clausula GROUP BY toda

Comment: Repare que você esta pegando o MIN de todos os campos. Não sei a lógica de seu programa, mas pode haver situações que estará vindo mais de um registro e você estará fazendo um merge entre eles e pegando sempre o menor valor para todos os campos. Isso pode ser desejável em algumas condições porém pode ser perigoso e trazer consequências.

Comment: Mas se eu tirar a clausula group by vai dar erro pois min é função de grupo entao group by seria obrigatorio, ou estou errado?

Comment: Esta errado. MIN, MAX, SUM são funcões agregadoras e não precisam estar em GROUP BY, alias se estiver o MIN e/ou MAX não funciona. 
Alias, isso me faz pensar que você colocou o GROUP BY em todos os campos e MIN da resposta não funcionou. Espero não ter te confundido. rsrs

Comment: Olá Reginaldo, dessa última forma que você falou ele só traz 1 registro dos 254 existentes, no caso ele traz apenas o IDCHAMADO 1 e mais nada.

Comment: Editei a resposta. Execute como esta lá.

Comment: Com alguns ajustes no seu último SQL consegui chegar ao resultado esperado, muito obrigado Reginaldo, tenha uma ótima semana, abraços!